# How to Add Auto fields that user can edit

Tags: django, django-models

I am creating an model in this I need a auto generated field other than id ....

An `AutoField`

Sequence #. Auto increment # 10,20,30,  - For sequential ordering. (Auto Generated - but user can edit)

It need to increment on the basis of 10 also the user can able to edit it .....

It's my requirement

Here is my model:

```
class Abc(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    order = models.AutoField()
```

How to generate it on the basis of 10... Also how can user edit it

Answer (score 1):

Django won't allow you to use more than one `AutoField` in the model. See more [Documentation.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/models/#automatic-primary-key-fields)

> If you’d like to specify a custom primary key, specify
>   `primary_key=True` on one of your fields. If Django sees you’ve
>   explicitly set `Field.primary_key`, it won’t add the automatic id
>   column.
>
> Each model requires exactly one field to have `primary_key=True` (either
>   explicitly declared or automatically added).

The solution using `IntegerField`:

```
class Abc(models.Model):
    def increment_by_ten():
        try:
            inst = Abs.objects.latest('id')
            return inst.order + 10
        except Abs.DoesNotExist:
            return 10

    order = models.IntegerField(unique=True, default=increment_by_ten)
```

Comment: It will not work.... What happens if I edited the order of latest .

For example if I change the order to 10 .... then it again becomes 20 for the next one right